# How to Pass/access value from javascript to C# page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have tried below approach.

1. I used one hidden field on aspx page named hdnTime.
2. Then I assigned value to hidden field in javascript function.

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
        function getLocalTimeZone() {
            document.getElementById('ctl00_bcr_hdnTime').value = 10;
            var hidden = document.getElementById('ctl00_bcr_hdnTime');
            var timezone = String(new Date());             
            hidden.value = timezone.substring(timezone.lastIndexOf('(') + 1).replace(')', '').trim();             
        }
   ```
3. Then on C# page load I tried below code.

   ```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "disp_confirm", "getLocalTimeZone()", true);

   string test = hdnTime.Value;
   ```

But I am getting blank value for hdnTime.

Please let me know if I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

`Page_Load` event is executed before `document.ready` so anything set in `document.ready` won't be available in `Page_Load event`

You can set value on `click` of a button than in `c#` you can get that value.

Comment: I need to access client timezone on page load event and depending upon the time zone, I need to perform some operations.

Comment: Are you sure id of hidden is `ctl00_bcr_hdnTime` ?